# Unexpected number of arguments when calling EM_JS function

Tags: emscripten

I have this code in `test.c`:

```c
#include "emscripten.h"

EM_JS(int, get_int, (), {
    return 0;
});

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return get_int();
}
```

I compile: `emcc test.c`, and it emits a warning: `warning: unexpected number of arguments 0 in call to 'get_int', should be 1`

Why does `get_int()` expect an argument? My code does what I want it to when I use it in context, but I would like to deal with this warning properly.

Interestingly, renaming `test.c` to `test.cpp` is enough to remove the warning, but I am hoping to use C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird corner case in the C language: `int foo()` actually receives a single parameter, it is variadic like `printf`. Basically, it means, "I don't know what the arguments are." To actually say "no arguments", write `int foo(void)`.

C++ does this differently (arguably, better!) as you noticed, `int foo()` in C++ does mean "no arguments".

So either use `(void)` there, or use a C++ file.